# How to customize values on x-axis in qplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `qplot` with the following code.

```
 qplot(topN, F1Score, data = evaluation.data, geom = c("point", "line"), color= Recommender, main = "F1 score...")
```

The x-axis is `topN` and y-axis is `F1Score`. The x-axis is supposed to only contain integer values. But there's decimals as shown in the Figure. **How can I customize this to use only integer values?**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_continuous`.

```
qplot(topN, 
      F1Score, 
      data = evaluation.data, 
      geom = c("point", "line"), 
      color= Recommender, 
      main = "F1 score...") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(5, 10, 15))
```

Also your color guide does not seem very useful. I would probably remove the legend.

```
+ scale_color_discrete(guide="none")
```

Comment: it works. Thanks for the reply. BTW, is there a way to use different shape for each line? Currently all lines use a point.